# Testing console command that uses kernel.terminate event (KernelTestCase)

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I want to test a symfony 4 console command. 
Importantly, I want to test the situation after all `kernel.terminate` eventlisteners have finished. To demonstrate here, I have a most simple listener that var_dumps a string:

```
class NotificationCenter implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function onException()
    {
        $this->wasExceptionThrown = true;
    }

    public function onTerminate()
    {
        if ($this->wasExceptionThrown) {
            return;
        }
        var_dump("Hiho from terminate");
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        $listeners = [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => ['onException', 1024],
            KernelEvents::TERMINATE => ['onTerminate', 1024],
        ];
        if (class_exists('Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents')) {
            $listeners[class_exists('Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleErrorEvent') ? ConsoleEvents::ERROR : ConsoleEvents::EXCEPTION] = ['onException', 1024];
            $listeners[ConsoleEvents::TERMINATE] = ['onTerminate', 1024];
        }
        return $listeners;
    }
    public function reset()
    {
        $this->wasExceptionThrown = false;
    }
}
```

So, with this eventlistener enabled, any call to any command (or http route) outputs this string.

According to [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/console.html#testing-commands), I have created a Test case:

```
class MissingDataNotifyCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
    }

    public function testHiHoIsThere()
    {
        $application = new Application(static::$kernel);
        $command = $application->find('debug:event-dispatcher');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(['command'  => $command->getName()]);
        $this->assertContains('Hiho from terminate', $commandTester->getDisplay());
    }
}
```

**But the assertion fails**. Funny enough, the debug command that var_dumps is listed under `kernel.terminate`.

### How can I make sure the `kernel.terminate` eventlisteners are dispatched during a `KernelTestCase`?

## Edit: my solution

Ok, with Tomas Votruba's help, I was able to find a (partial) solution:

```
class MissingDataNotifyCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
    }

    public function testHiHoIsThere()
    {
        $application = new Application(static::$kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);
        $application->setCatchExceptions(false);
        $stringInput = ['debug:event-dispatcher'];
        $input = new StringInput(implode(' ', $stringInput));
        $application->run($input, new NullOutput());
    }
}
```

The only problem I could not solve was to get the output of the command back into my code. Moreover, this somehow does run some framework/container code twice (once when booting the kernel inside the tests, once when executing the command).

Comment: Have you added `EventDispatcher` to `Application`?

Comment: AFAIK, the call to `self::bootKernel();` boots up the complete container: https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/0af4b5a59c8136a8044d40bf5ab44ee50acb79b4/Test/KernelTestCase.php#L62

Comment: I test commands with own container without FrameworkBundle (too magic for my needs), so I don't know. Could you verify it by dumping `$application`?

Comment: Wow, this worked!

Comment: Great! What exactly? So I can update the answer for other to come :)

Answer (score 0):

I double checked and it looks like you're testing Console, not Kernel. They're 2 different classes.

- Kernel terminate event [is invoked here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/a928d2b88de3370baccb5f630aa95645feed0952/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L104).
- Console Application "terminate" event [is invoked here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/1d3ce9ba87af9ef6594583109aaf418185473526/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php#L934).

**Try adding [console terminate event](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/1d3ce9ba87af9ef6594583109aaf418185473526/src/Symfony/Component/Console/ConsoleEvents.php#L36) to subscriber - `console.terminate`.**

```
class YourSubscriber implements EventSubccriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::TERMINATE => 'someFunction',
            ConsoleEvents::TERMINATE => 'someFunction',
        ];
    }

    public function someFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I already cared for that, as my listener builds upon the standard listener as here: https://github.com/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/blob/master/EventListener/EmailSenderListener.php. I extended my initial post above

Comment: I tried to emulate your issue locally and the subscriber is really not registered - there are only 3 system ones. Not sure why. `CommandTester` scope is limited and doesn't provide real 1:1 cycle to real command run with application and all. That's why [I run commands with Application](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/blob/6c889dc0b055718bd7bc8f796b1c657ca1c77b67/packages/Statie/tests/Console/Command/GenerateCommandTest.php#L27-L51) and never deal with such problems.